# wp_query to print posts if have X custom field value

Tags: wp-query, custom-field

I'm trying to print posts if any posts have custom field value X.
My code is working correctly but this is not working if the custom field has multiple values X, Y, Z.
Location is a CF Meta and X is value.
And at here [`get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Location', true)));`] Location Meta is also inserted on a page where I want to output and on that page there are also have CF value X. If the post's values are X, Y, Z then the code fails to print posts.
Sorry for lacking skills of explanation here.

```
<?php
    $posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => 10,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'meta_key' => 'Location',
    'meta_value' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Location',true)));
    if($posts) {
        foreach($posts as $post) {
?>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
         <?php 
             }
         } 
         ?>
         <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: `wp_reset_query` should only be used after a call to `query_posts`. Is there a reason you used `get_posts` instead of `WP_Query`? Functions such as `the_title` require that the current post be set, which a `get_posts` loop doesn't do automatically and isn't present in the questions code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `meta_query`, it can handle arrays and strings.

So something like this

```
// get location meta, will be easier to determine what is the type of value
$location = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Location',true);

$posts = get_posts([
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'meta_query'     => [
        [
            'key'     => 'Location',
            'value'   => $location,
            'compare' => is_array($location) ? 'IN' : '='
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Now you can do all the rest as usual.

So what we did here is

1. get and assing `Location` meta to a variable, `$location`
2. add that variable as value in the `meta_query`
3. based on the type of value of the variable we create the compare logic

---

By the way, `get_permalink()` and `the_title()` will output/return the link and title of the current post, NOT the looped post.

When using `get_posts()` they are available as object properties, so like this

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
    $post->post_title; // the post title
    get_permalink($post->ID) // the looped post permalink, we need to pass the looped post ID as argument to "tell" get_permalink what link we need
}
```

Comment: Note that the final code block will not trigger filters the way `the_title` does, you should instead setup postdata so that the current post is set, then sue the appropriate cleanup function afterwards